# Minimal example wanted showing texview incrementing a count on a timer?

Tags: android, timer

In c it would be: 
while(1){
  i++;
  printf("%d \r",i);
}
I assume the textview and the variable and the timer get created in oncreate, then there is a timer handler with an increment and a settext and a sleep? Seeing how to do this in androidese would really clarify things I think. Thanks.

Comment: What have you done? It looks like an undone homework..

Comment: I highly doubt that any class would have a homework assignment like this that deals with a mobile platform.

Comment: @syninc I had a homework like that months ago... that what I wrote that.

Comment: In what class?  That's pretty awesome

Answer (score 2):

This could be done with a timer... something like this:

```
mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

Timer timer = new Timer();
IncrementTask task = new IncrementTask(mTextView);
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1000);
```

.... and a subclass of TimerTask:

```
class IncrementTask extends TimerTask {
    WeakReference<TextView> mRef;
    int counter = 0;
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    public IncrementTask(TextView text) {
        mRef = new WeakReference<TextView>(text);
    }

    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mRef.get().setText("counter " + counter);
                counter++;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The foreground task doesnt time out unles you starve it for 4 seconds. Surely one could increment a variable and update a textview in a 500mhz processor in microseconds. I think its inconceivable to have to spawn a task to increment a variable. Its not a cpu intensive task. I was hoping to see a small elegant and understandable solution. The only part of java that I'm understanding is that its just like c but no pointers... I aint getting a lot of the subtle nuances yet...